# Mapping uWSGI processes to specific cpu cores

Tags: load-balancing, central-processing-unit, uwsgi

I have 2 sites on my server (debian) with 4 cpu cores.
For both of them I use `workers=2` and `cpu-affinity=1` so workers are
mapped to cpu 0 and 1 for both sites like that:

```
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 19345)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 19346, cores: 1)
mapping worker 1 to CPUs: 0
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 19347, cores: 1)
mapping worker 2 to CPUs: 1
```

I don't want to use 4 workers (obviously, in this case load would spread equally between all cores) to reduce memory usage so I wonder if I
can somehow map workers to specific cpu cores?
Taking example above, would be nice to have 0 and 1 cpu mapped to
workers of the first site and 2 and 3 for the second one.

Also I found some useful (but not enough) info here:
http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2011-March/001594.html

Thanks.

Comment: One word: why? Many people think that CPU pinning is a good thing. It rarely if ever provides *any* performance increase over just letting the kernel's CPU scheduler do its thing.

Comment: Exactly. The kernel is better at this than you are in almost all cases.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but pinning is happening anyway. As I posted, workers are mapped to cpu 0 and 1. For both sites. And they don't switch. So if uWSGI would map them to another that would be nice as load on all cores would be equal.